# Add a new row to a table once form is submitted. -JQuery, Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am using ajax.beginform and and calling a json object in my Controller to render form objects after a form is submitted. I want to  insert a new table row that grabs data from the database.  What is the correct way to do that?  I need help in the jquery function.  Here's my code.

**View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Controller", null, new AjaxOptions

        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = "RenderObjectsAfterSubmit(data);"
        }))

{ 

<div>Request # <span id="ID"></span></div>
<div>
    @Html.Label("Name")
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>

<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table> 
}
```

**Jquery Function**

```
function RenderObjectsAfterSubmit(data) {
    if (data != null && data.model != null) {
        $("#ID").html(data.model.Id);
        $("<tr><td>$('#Name').html(data.model.Name);</td> </tr>").insertAfter("#myTable");  **Here is where I need help.**
    }
    onSuccess(data, '', '#ajaxresult', '', '#btnSubmit');
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult SubmitForm(Model model)
{

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    try
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            success=true,
            model=model
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on how to write this part.  I want to insert a new row into table (myTable).

Comment: Are you trying to insert a Name into html table which was given in a form to database?

Comment: Mahesh, yes.  I would like to insert a new row into the html table  after I click submit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("<tr><td>"+$('#Name').text()+"</td> </tr>").appendTo("#myTable");
```

Comment: Yes i forgot html() returned an object maybe now it's acceptable.

Comment: text() returns an object too.  I'm thinking this has something to do with how JSON is called. Looking through my code, I do not see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in onsuccess function

try

```
$("#myTable").append("<tr><td>"+$('#Name').val()+"</td> </tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the way I was doing things.  I got it to work by just adding an Id to OnSuccess function. So, it looks like this.

onSuccess(data, '#myTable', '#ajaxresult', '', '#btnSubmit');